# Split dataframe by certain condition but keep the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe "bb" like this:

```
Response                                Unique Count
I love it so much!                      246_0    1
This is not bad, but can be better.     246_1    2
Well done, let's do it.                 247_0    1
```

If count is lager than 1, I would like to split the string and make the dataframe "bb" become this: (result I expected)

```
Response                                Unique
I love it so much!                      246_0    
This is not bad                         246_1_0    
but can be better.                      246_1_1
Well done, let's do it.                 247_0
```

My code:

```
bb = DataFrame(bb[bb['Count'] > 1].Response.str.split(',').tolist(), index=bb[bb['Count'] > 1].Unique).stack()
bb = bb.reset_index()[[0, 'Unique']]
bb.columns = ['Response','Unique']
bb=bb.replace('', np.nan)
bb=bb.dropna()
print(bb)
```

But the result is like this:

```
           Response  Unique
0  This is not bad    246_1
1  but can be better. 246_1
```

How can I keep the original dataframe in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split only values per condition with to new helper `Series` and then add counter values by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) only per duplicated index values by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
s = df.loc[df.pop('Count') > 1, 'Response'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df1 = df.join(s.reset_index(drop=True, level=1).rename('Response1'))
df1['Response'] = df1.pop('Response1').fillna(df1['Response'])

mask = df1.index.duplicated(keep=False)
df1.loc[mask, 'Unique'] += df1[mask].groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_')
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
              Response   Unique
0   I love it so much!    246_0
1      This is not bad  246_1_0
2   but can be better.  246_1_1
3           Well done!    247_0
```

EDIT: If need `_0` for all another values remove mask:

```
s = df.loc[df.pop('Count') > 1, 'Response'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df1 = df.join(s.reset_index(drop=True, level=1).rename('Response1'))
df1['Response'] = df1.pop('Response1').fillna(df1['Response'])

df1['Unique'] += df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_')
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
              Response   Unique
0   I love it so much!  246_0_0
1      This is not bad  246_1_0
2   but can be better.  246_1_1
3           Well done!  247_0_0
```

Comment: Very neat, thank you! Did you add "_0" in the end in other Unique too while you edited a few minutes ago? I think it's a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Step wise we can solve this problem the following:

1. Split your dataframes by count
2. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) function to explode the string to rows
3. We `groupby` on index and use `cumcount` to get the correct `unique` column values.
4. Finally we `concat` the dataframes together again.

---

```
df1 = df[df['Count'].ge(2)] # all rows which have a count 2 or higher
df2 = df[df['Count'].eq(1)] # all rows which have count 1

df1 = explode_str(df1, 'Response', ',') # explode the string to rows on comma delimiter

# Create the correct unique column
df1['Unique'] = df1['Unique'] + '_' + df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount().astype(str)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().drop('Count', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
              Response   Unique
0   I love it so much!    246_0
1      This is not bad  246_1_0
2   but can be better.  246_1_1
3           Well done!    247_0
```

---

Function used from linked answer:

```
def explode_str(df, col, sep):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.count(sep) + 1)
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: sep.join(s).split(sep)})
```